# Localize PList Strings (Like NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription) Post-Compilation

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, plist, info.plist

I was wondering if there is anyway to localize strings coming from the Info.plist of an iOS application AFTER compiling the project in order to prevent having a bunch of localization folders and a plist file for each language.

Comment: And where would do you put those strings ?

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you want to store localized strings differently in application bundle? Or, maybe, strip "unused" localizations? In second case - you cannot, actually, know which localizations are unused for any user. Maybe, on-demand resources may address this issue.